# Cron.yaml not creating re-occuring task

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ubuntu, cron, yaml

I am trying to have a php script in my google app engine by run every 1 minute using the `Cron.yaml` procedure.

My cron.yaml file looks like below

```
cron:
 - description: "ping apple apns service"
  url: /folder/ios_push_notification
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

and my `app.yaml` file is as follows:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /folder/ios_push_notification
  script: ios_push_notification.php
```

I upload all my files using the google cloud shell downloaded to my computer with the `gcloud app deploy` command.

To clarify, all my files work. I can go to the script through the url on a browser. The only part that isn't working is the script isn't being run every 15 seconds.

Comment: Your first example is invalid YAML, try it e.g. with some online parser.

Comment: Yea `cron.yaml` doesn't support seconds to my knowledge, had to change to minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

"You can use `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` to upload cron jobs."